# How to setup IIS7 ISAPI/CGI Restriction for Delphi SOAP executable?

Tags: windows-7, iis, iis-7

When trying to run my executable I kept receiving an

> error 404.2 error
>   The page you are
>   requesting cannot be served because of
>   the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list
>   settings on the Web server.

I fixed it by going into the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions screen off of the server level in the IISManager, Clicking on the Edit Feature Settings link on the right in the actions box, then checking to allow unspecified CGI and ISAPI modules.

However I would like to know the correct way to make this work? I am thinking there is a restriction I need to add (and of course set to allow) to specify which module to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One the Restrictions screen what you are supposed to add is the path to the web service (File) that you want to be able to run.